# How okay is it to call vuex actions asynchronously from router.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have already achieved this. But is there any drawback of doing this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Please provide code sample.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case I believe, but most likely if you are doing it, there is a good chance it is spaghetti code.

The drawback is, most likely your structure is not solid